# Make Razor fetch Views from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to implement vertical slice architecture. I have my Program.cs in Web project and my Views are coupled with Controllers in Core project. Razor won't find them when they are placed like that, but easily locates them in Web/Views, for example (relative path)

I register my controllers with views like that:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); // I also temporarily have some Razor Pages in my system.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Faction).Assembly); // Add controllers from another assembly
```

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorPages();
```

```
return View("/Features/Statistics/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal.cshtml", viewModel);
```

Produces

- InvalidOperationException: The view '/Features/Statistics/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
  /Features/Statistics/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal/GetLast5GamesStatsGlobal.cshtml*

File is located on this location, but in another project

How do I make them visible to the engine?

I have tried respecifying paths in different formats, using absolute path.

Comment: Have a look at [Create reusable UI using the Razor class library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Could you please include your project structure for `RCL`? Have you created both host and consumer app?

Comment: @QingGuo I like it, but it feels semantically wrong to make project RCL, since views make up only 3-5% of it

Comment: Creating a RCL project just means creating a vanilla project that has the dependencies required to create razor pages and views automatically referenced for you.  Just like any other dependency, if only 1 line of code in a million requires that dependency then that dependency must be referenced.